# AWS Lambda Publish - error NU1605: Detected package downgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I use mysql database connection to a MySQL database with Entity Framework Core (`MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore v8.0.22`). I use .NET Core 3.1.

I get this error when publishing:

> Error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
>
> Error NU1605:  Lambdaapp2 -> MySql.Data 8.0.22 -> SSH.NET 2016.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.unix.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0)
>
> Error NU1605:  Lambdaapp2 -> MySql.Data 8.0.22 -> SSH.NET 2016.1.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.0.11)
>
> Error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
>
> Error NU1605:  Lambdaapp2 -> MySql.Data 8.0.22 -> SSH.NET 2016.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.unix.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded from MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore v8.0.22 to v8.0.21 and it magically started working.  It looks like they updated lots of dependencies between 8.0.21 and 8.0.22 and some of these don't play well with AWS Lambda.